# compare datagridview column value with listbox items and get the result to another column

Tags: vb.net

i made a form with datagridview which get its values from excel file and the make some changes for its columns to prepare it to be saved in sql database

so i need your help to compare one datagridview column with listbox items and get the result in another column
for example 
in datagridview column value "MR Naveed" and my listbox "MR Naveed" is "MN"
i need to check every "Mr Naveed" to be "MN"
i made this code

```
Dim s As String
s = ListBox1.FindStringExact(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = s
```

it works but the result is the value array like 0,1,2 in the listbox
but i need the name

Comment: Is there any ideas .. please??

Answer (score 0):

FindStringExact returns an Integer index to what you needed to find. You are setting this index into your DataGridView.

Have your tried:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = ListBox1.Items(s).Text
```

Edit: This might work I am writing a solution to test it now. I will be back with another answer if anything changes but the problem remains being that you are simply creating a string of the index locations in the ListBox you want.

eg. If your work is in the 4-7 spots of the box your string will be 4,5,6,7

The form I made below is a basic example of what I think is going wrong. You need reference the Items in the listbox by the index you have returned to you from FindStringExact

[Test Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIePE.png)

```
Public Class Form1

Dim s As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    s = ListBox1.FindStringExact("test")

    labelIndex.Text = s

    labelValue.Text = ListBox1.Items(s)

End Sub
```

End Class